# Concatenate DateTimePicker in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I concatenate the values of two datetimepicker?

```
DateTimePicker1 - this is for the the DATE mm/dd/yyyy
DateTimePicker2 - this is for the the TIME hh:mm:ss
```

I want a value of ... `mm/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss` in one variable, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(dtp1.Year, dtp1.Month, dtp1.Day, dtp2.Hour, dtp2.Minute, dtp2.Second);
```

Please check the order of the parameters, I am writing from memory. 
Here dtp1 is a DateTime object from the first datetime picker.

Comment: Dim ArrivalDate As Date = New DateTime(dtp_ArrivalDate.Value.Year, dtp_ArrivalDate.Value.Month, dtp_ArrivalDate.Value.Day, dtp_ArrivalTime.Value.Hour, dtp_ArrivalTime.Value.Minute, dtp_ArrivalTime.Value.Second)